# How can I run Yesod's DB actions in the REPL?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

It is easy to run DB actions in the normal `Handler` workflow, since the `runDB` function can be used to transform the `SqlPersistM` actions into `Handler` ones.

But there is no such way to convert `SqlPersistM` directly into `IO` using the default app settings. Looking at the `Foundation.hs` as its defined in the application scaffold, there is the following instance

```
instance YesodPersist App where
    type YesodPersistBackend App = SqlBackend
    runDB action = do
        master <- getYesod
        runSqlPool action $ appConnPool master
instance YesodPersistRunner App where
    getDBRunner = defaultGetDBRunner appConnPool
```

which basically uses `runSqlPool` with the app's config, but I don't see an easy way how to leverage this to access the config form within the REPL.

TL;DR: **What I'm looking for is simply being able to do something like `runDB $ selectList [...] [...]` from within cabal repl in my Yesod app**, without having to duplicate the setup that Yesod scaffolding does out of the box.

Comment: To clarify, are you using the yesod scaffolding? If so, you can use [these functions](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/bb7897b67021f42aa38c7f2fedd03be81f8980c9/Application.hs#L161-L171) to run handler actions and DB queries. Example usage: `db $ selectList [UserName ==. "foo"] []`

Comment: @MaxGabriel I'd recommend making that comment an answer, it's a good demonstration of how to achieve Jakub's goal.

Comment: Good call @MichaelSnoyman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the Yesod scaffolding, the [`handler` and `db` functions](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/bb7897b67021f42aa38c7f2fedd03be81f8980c9/Application.hs#L161-L171) are provided to let you run handler actions and database queries, respectively, from the repl:

```
$ cabal repl

db $ selectList [UserName ==. "foo"] []
```

Edit: I've also updated [Yesod's wiki page on GHCi](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/ghci) with this information. It includes more examples and covers some advanced usage, like using the debugger.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for.